# O que é e para que serve o GDI Scaling

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Acabei de instalar o Delphi mais novo e percebei um tal de GDI Scaling Alguém sabe dizer que é, para que serve e como funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Isso significa que se você usar o Windows e tiver um monitor de alta resolução de 4K ou semelhante, o IDE será renderizado de forma nítida e clara na tela. Na verdade, se você tiver duas telas com escalas diferentes, poderá ter janelas IDE diferentes nessas várias telas e cada uma será renderizada de forma perfeita, nítida e clara, em cada monitor.

Fonte:https://blogs.embarcadero.com/pt/new-in-rad-studio-11-high-dpi-ide-and-form-designing/

Conforme imagem abaixa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]